# Update Statement Sql Access Double Inner join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following command

```
UPDATE tbl1
SET tbl1.val = 7
FROM ((tbl3 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl3.ID = tbl2.ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl1 ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID) 
WHERE tbl3.ID = 2
AND tbl1.val = [val];
```

The innerjoins work as i use them elsewhere. However, i get the following error

"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression"

I had this before and it turned out to be brackets because access is funny. However, i haven't managed to figure this one out.

Comment: MS Access does not -- to the best of my knowledge -- support a `FROM` clause in `UPDATE`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Any idea of another way of updating a value with two innerjoins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `exists`:

```
UPDATE tbl1
SET tbl1.val = 7
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tbl3 INNER JOIN
                   tbl2 ON tbl3.ID = tbl2.ID
              WHERE tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID AND 
                    tbl3.ID = 2
             ) AND
      tbl1.val = [val];
```

Comment: Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, MS Access *does* support `UPDATE ... JOIN` (similar to MySQL/MariaDB). Simply replace `FROM` with `UPDATE` and move to first clause:

```
UPDATE ((tbl3 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl3.ID = tbl2.ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl1 ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID) 
SET tbl1.val = 7
WHERE tbl3.ID = 2
  AND tbl1.val = [val];
```